# Adding AUTO_INCREMENT

Tags: sql-server, auto-increment

I have a table where I've merged 2 tables into one.
One of the tables had an ID (primary key).

Now I got a merged table where some of the ID is 0.

I now try to restore and fill out the `0` with AUTO_INCREMENT so I
get a table with unique numbers (and not lose the one already there )

Someone got a god solution here ?

Comment: Use an `UPDATE` with `ROW_NUMBER`? Also `AUTO_INCREMENT` isn't a T-SQL "thing"; T-SQL uses `IDENTITY`.

Comment: Either `IDENTITY` or `AUTO_INCREMENT` generate incrementing values for new rows. They don't fill existing rows

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the fact that you have a bunch of `0`'s in the table implies 2 additional problems:

1. The "ID" column is not a Primary Key or dose not have a Unique Index on it; meaning that duplicates were inserted
2. The column is (likely) no longer an `IDENTITY`.

Firstly, You'll need to get the new values in there. This can be done with an updatable CTE, with `ROW_NUMBER` and a windowed `MAX`

First some sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.TestTable (ID int NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable (ID)
VALUES(1),(2),(3),(0),(0),(0);
```

And now to `UPDATE` the rows with `0`:

```sql
WITH RNs AS(
    SELECT ID,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CASE ID WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) + --If you have a way of determining the order, change the ORDER BY
           MAX(ID) OVER () AS [NewID]
    FROM dbo.TestTable)
UPDATE RNs
SET ID = [NewID]
WHERE ID = 0;
```

Now we (probably) need to fix the table and get the `IDENTITY` column in there. You can't change a column to an `IDENTITY`, so we'll need to create a new one and ensure it follows the value of the existing ID.

First, therefore, we need to add a `CLUSTERED` index to the table, so that the new `IDENTITY` will use that to generate its value:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.TestTable ADD CONSTRAINT PK_TestTable PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID);
```

Now we can add the new `IDENTITY` column:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.TestTable ADD IdentityID int IDENTITY NOT NULL;
```

Then we need to `DROP` the Primary Key we just created, and then the old column:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.TestTable DROP CONSTRAINT PK_TestTable ;
ALTER TABLE dbo.TestTable DROP COLUMN ID;
```

And then, finally, we can rename the new column, and then recreate the Primary Key:

```
EXEC sys.sp_rename N'dbo.TestTable.IdentityID','ID','COLUMN';
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.TestTable ADD CONSTRAINT PK_TestTable PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID);
```